# Calculate estimate revenue per period with zeros in between

Tags: finance, estimation

I'm trying to do the maths to calculate the estimate revenue for a given period (day, week, month, year)

So for example, if I have data for 30 days, I need to estimate what would be my income tomorrow.

At the moment what I'm doing is quite simple:

- Calculate growth rate per day for the past 7 days
- Do the average of each of those rates (for example, 20%)
- Now apply that growth rate to the previous day

The problem I'm having is having to deals with days where revenue is 0.

I can't calculate the growth rate for it.
The way I'm doing it now is:

> growth rate = ((day - previous_day) / previous_day) * 100

So I definitely can't divide by 0 if any previous day has $0 revenue.
And it also wouldn't make sense to say my growth rate is 100% is one day it goes from 0 to 1.

What should I do in these cases?

Perhaps ignore those previous days and not taking them to account for the growth rate calculation?
Should I also ignore any day which value is also 0?

Right now I'm ignoring it, but then I get things like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 259.39
    [4] => 259.39  //estimated
)
```

Which do not look right at all.

Comment: [tag:complex-analysis] is for calculus with complex numbers (involving the square root of $-1$); I changed that tag to [tag:finance]

Comment: What kind of data you are referring to? Explain exacly what kind of data you have.